# how can we define real number to form of a (first-order) structure of type $\mathcal L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers, universal-algebra

We know that  :

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of all real numbers. Then:
>
> 1-) The set $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, meaning that addition and multiplication are defined and have the usual properties.
>
> 2-)The field $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered, meaning that there is a total order ≥ such that, for all real numbers $x, y$ and $z$:
>
> if $x ≥ y$ then $x + z ≥ y + z$;
>
> if $x ≥ 0$ and $y ≥ 0$ then $xy ≥ 0$.
>
> The order is Dedekind-complete; that is: every non-empty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with an upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound (also called supremum) in $\mathbb{R}$ .

And also we study in universal algebra that :

> If $\mathcal{L}$ is a first-order language, then a (first-order) structure of type $\mathcal L$(or  $\mathcal{L}$-structure) is an ordered pair $\mathbf{A}=\langle  A , L \rangle $ , with $A = ∅$, where $L$ consists of a family $R$ of
> fundamental relations $r^{\mathbf{A} }$ on $A$ indexed by ${\mathcal R }$ (with the arity of $r^{\mathbf{A} }$ equal to the arity of $r$ ,
> for $r ∈ \mathbf{R} $) and a family $F$ of fundamental operations $f^{\mathbf{A}}$ on $A$ indexed by $\mathcal{F}$ (with the arity
> of $f^{\mathbf{A}}$ equal to the arity of $f$, for $f \in \mathcal{F}$). A is called the universe of $A$, and in practice we usually write just $r$ for $r^{\mathbf{A}}$ and $f$ for $f^{\mathbf{A}}$
> A. If $\mathcal R = ∅$ then $\mathbf A$ is an algebra; if $\mathcal F = ∅ $then $\mathbf A$
> is a relational structure. If $\mathcal{L}$ is finite, say $\mathcal F = \lbrace {f_1, . . . , f_m}\rbrace $, $\mathcal 
> R = \lbrace r_1, . . . , r_n \rbrace$, then we often
> write
> $\langle A, f_1, . . . , f_m, r_1, . . . , r_n \rangle$
> instead of $\langle A, L \rangle $.

---

Now how can we define real number to form of a (first-order) structure of type $\mathcal L$ ?

Comment: Why isn't $(\mathbb{R};+,\times,<)$ (or similar) satisfactory?

Comment: I've read your original post, *and* all your comments on Noah's answer, and I still have absolutely no idea what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb{R};+,\times,<)$ (or similar) is already a perfectly satisfying first-order structure. There are also various other natural expansions, like $(\mathbb{R}; +,\times,\sin)$ - e.g. we can even consider $\mathbb{R}$ together with *all real functions* (this very-huge-language picture is relevant e.g. in nonstandard analysis) - and which specific first-order structure is appropriate to put on $\mathbb{R}$ depends on context.

EDIT: Let me make the point of the above explicit: **there is no "unique right" way to view $\mathbb{R}$ as a first-order structure.** Sometimes we care about $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field; then $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ - or any of the *definitionally-equivalent* variants, like $(\mathbb{R};+,-,\times,<)$, or even $(\mathbb{R};+,-,\times,^{-1},<)$ if we either view $^{-1}$ as a *relation* or allow *partial* functions in our semantics - is the right approach. In other situations we want more (as in nonstandard analysis mentioned above), or less (if we just want to consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a group), or just ... different (maybe we want to think about addition and $e^x$, but not multiplication!).

- Let me mention one particular type of reason we might *actively want* to work with a more limited language. When we limit the language, we often see powerful "tameness" phenomena. Most importantly, the structure $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ (and many of its variants) is **o-minimal**, but $\mathbb{R}$ with *all* functions isn't o-minimal. Precisely what o-minimality *is* isn't important right now; the point is that knowing that a structure is o-minimal lets us prove interesting things about it, and so we can prove things about $\mathbb{R}$ as a field (that is, we can prove results in real algebraic geometry) by thinking about $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ (and its relatives) *rather than* the more "expanded" structures. So more expressive power isn't always a good thing!

---

Now you might object that Dedekind-completeness doesn't show up anywhere in the above. This is because Dedekind-completeness isn't a first-order property, so it won't be folded into the definition in any explicit way; rather, it will be a property this particular structure happens to have, but others like it may not - e.g. there will be ordered fields elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ which aren't Dedekind-complete. Put another way, the "least upper bound" function is *infinitary*, and so doesn't fit into the framework of first-order structures.

Comment: in $(\mathbb{R} ; +, \times , < ) $ Does not exist $(^{-1} ,- )$ and relation of $(=)$ .

Comment: @Almot1960 "$=$" is built automatically into first-order logic; you don't have to include it separately. $^{-1}$ and $-$ (and $0$ and $1$) are meanwhile definable from $+$ and $\times$ so they don't have to be included (although of course you can include them if you want). Actually, what I wrote is redundant: "$<$" is definable from $+$ and $\times$ (because $a<b$ iff $\exists c(c\times c+a=b)$). The point, though, is that $(i)$ precisely *what* structure you put on a given set depends on your particular intentions (e.g. do you want $\sin$ or not?), and $(ii)$ often we can make do with little.

Comment: Also, there is a slight issue with $^{-1}$, namely that it is only a **partial** function. We can modify the semantics of first-order logic to allow partial functions, or work instead with the inverse *relation* $ab=1$, or work with the modified inverse function $a^{\sim 1}$ given by $a^{\sim 1}={1\over a}$ for $a\not=0$ and $0^{\sim 1}=0$ (say).

Comment: Suppose :we don't want define $ \lbrace - , ^{-1} , 0, 1 < , = \rbrace$ by $\lbrace+ ,\times ,... \rbrace$
then how we can define $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Almot1960 I don't understand what you're asking. $(\mathbb{R}; +,\times,<)$ is a perfectly good first-order structure. If you want to make the structure bigger, you can: for example, $(\mathbb{R}; +,\times,<,-)$ is *also* a perfectly valid structure although it is redundant since "$-$" can be defined in terms of the other operations, and $(\mathbb{R};+,\times,<,\sin)$ is a *non-redundant* expansion of $(\mathbb{R};+,\times,<)$. But all of this seems beside the point: **once you decide** what functions/relations/constants on $\mathbb{R}$ you care about, there's your structure!

Comment: I want to make the structure bigger such that it includes all operators and relations .

Comment: @Almot1960 If by "all operators and relations" you really mean **all**, then this is the approach I mentioned in the first paragraph in the context of nonstandard analysis ("we can even consider $\mathbb{R}$ together with *all real functions* (this very-huge-language picture is relevant e.g. in nonstandard analysis)"): just make every function and relation specifically named! That's a perfectly valid structure, even if it does have an absurdly large language.

Comment: My definition : $\mathbb{R}$ is a structure $(\mathbb{R} ; + ,\times , - ,^{-1} ,0 ,1 , = , >)$ Is this complete?

Comment: But maybe you mean "all operators and relations *that we care about in mathematics*." In this case, your request is too vague to be immediately answered; different mathematicians will care about different things at different times. The point, though, is that you have *complete freedom* in deciding what sort of structure to put on a given set; it's not always good to include all functions, but sometimes you do want to, and that's fine!

Comment: @Almot1960 Yet again, it depends what you mean by "complete." (And you don't need "$=$.") It is certainly a valid structure; however, it doesn't let you define (for example) $\sin(x)$, $e^x$, the Dirichlet function, etc., and only you can decide whether you care. So again, **it depends what you want your structure to be able to do** (more precisely: what functions/relations/etc. do you want to be *definable in* the structure?).

Comment: why ("=" is built automatically into first-order logic; you don't have to include it separately) ?

Comment: (Also, you should use a different symbol to denote the *structure* versus its *underlying set*: e.g. refer to the structure as $\mathcal{R}$ and the underlying set is $\mathbb{R}$. We frequently conflate the two, but this is only an acceptable habit once the basics are fully mastered.)

Comment: @Almot1960 "why ("=" is built automatically into first-order logic; you don't have to include it separately) ?" It's just part of the definition of first-order logic. You could also consider first-order logic *without* negation (and lots of people used to), but generally including equality results in an easier-to-use mathematics without losing any interesting phenomena. But see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316648/differences-between-logic-with-and-without-equality) for some debate on this topic.

Comment: I mean from "complete" : all operators and relations that in principles of real number .

Comment: @Almot1960 "all operators and relations that in principles of real number" I have no idea what that means. Is exponentiation "in principles of real number?" Is $\sin$? Until you give me a *precise definition* of this, I can't tell you whether a given approach works or doesn't.